# Displaying terms and conditions in an alert dialog - android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm writing my own `forum` app. I've a `MaterialTextView`, I want to display an `Alert` showing terms and conditions with `OK` button. Here is the code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:text="@string/welcome_users"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

`Java code:`

```
MaterialTextView desc;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    desc = findViewById(R.id.desc);
    desc.setOnClickListener(v -> showAlert());
}  
private void showAlert() {
        // setup the alert builder
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Terms and Conditions");
        builder.setMessage("This is my message.");
        // add a button
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        // create and show the alert dialog
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

I've a sample Terms and Conditions like this: https://www.wikihow.com/Sample/Terms-and-Conditions-for-Forum.
I want to insert that into body (setMessage()) of that alert dialog. It is long, is there any better way to acheive it?

Comment: you can create custom dialog, put your text in a scroll view. So user can scroll to read it.